# Regex to match datetime between a word and end of line?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regex pattern matcher to extract the date from the last-modified and date in a raw http header response.
I am reading the header in with a buffered reader and then going through it line by line to find the required information.
The two I am having trouble with are

```
Date: Mon, 27 Jul 2009 12:28:53 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 22 Jul 2009 19:15:56 GMT
```

I wish to extract the datetime from the string representing the line, but I cant seem to find a regular expression that works :/
The expected output should look like

```
27 Jul 2009 12:28:53 GMT
```

I was trying this, but it is not working

```
(?<=Date:\s).*(?=\n)
```

Cheers
Corey

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What should the expected output look like?

Comment: Why not just use an HTTP library?

Comment: Try a capturing approach: [`(?:Date|Last-Modified):\s*(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/HuKWPH/1), and the result will be in Group 1 (`matcher.group(1)`).

Comment: You clearly have a pattern like `[Date|Last-Modified]: 3character, 2digit 3character 4digit 2digit:2digit:2digit 3character` (could slightly vary based on the local ...) So what is the problem to build a regex for that ?

Comment: So you don't want to match the day, right?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just `if (line.startsWith("Date:")) { String dateStr = line.substring(5).trim(); ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateStr, DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME); /*use date here*/ }`?

Comment: try this - `^Date: [\w]+, (.*)` Demo [here](https://regexr.com/3mok6)

Comment: Update to my comment above - [`(?:Date|Last-Modified):\s*\w+,\s*(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/HuKWPH/2)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this out:

```
(?<=(Last\\-Modified|Date):\\s(?:Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun),\\s)(.+)
```

In your sample input-output, you have not matched the day, and I've assumed that's intentional, and not a typo.

Trial [at this link](https://regex101.com/r/iIUzsa/1).

### Regex -

`(?<=(Last\\-Modified|Date):\\s(?:Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun),\\s)` is a positive look-behind to ensure that the match is preceded by `Date:` or `Last-Modified:` and a day

`(Last\\-Modified|Date):` checks for the presence of `Date:` or `Last-Modified:`

`\\s` is a single space

`(?:Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun),\\s` is a non-capturing group for any day, followed by a comma and a space. Do note that I have added this **only** because according to the question, days must be excluded, and if you do want to obtain them, just remove this part of the regex [as shown here](https://regex101.com/r/iIUzsa/2).

`(.+)` matches one or more characters, which is the actual date desired in the question.

[Here's a cheat sheet for regex conventions](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html), should you need it.

Implemented as follows:

```
String regex = "(?<=(Last\\-Modified|Date):\\s(?:Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun),\\s)(.+)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(YourString);
while(m.find())
{
    String date = m.group();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write it as:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:Date|Last-Modified)\\s*:[^,]+,\\s*(.*)");

String input =
            "Date: Mon, 27 Jul 2009 12:28:53 GMT\n" +
            "Last-Modified: Wed, 22 Jul 2009 19:15:56 GMT";

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Basically you want the find a line with:

- `Date` or `Last-Modified`: `(?:Date|Last-Modified)`
- Optionally followed by spaces: `\\s*`
- The literal `:`
- Followed by the day name and a comma: `[^,]+,`
- Followed by any spaces and your group of interest: `\\s*(.*)`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use regex? What about something like this:

```
String input = "Date: Mon, 27 Jul 2009 12:28:53 GMT";
String output = input.split(", ")[1];
```